# Is it possible to programmatically disable (or change) Blue Share Button within Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

Would anyone happen to know if the blue 'Share' button which is located within each of the Google Apps, such as Spreadsheets, Document (etc),  at the top right of the screen... can be i) Disabled (ie: greyed out), ii) removed or iii )re-purposed via use of the Google API?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the button, but you can control permissions, and setting to only owner can share would prevent others from sharing.

Update to answer comment:
As owner of the file, just under the invite people in the sharing UI, is an option to allow editors to add people or change permissions of the document.  If you set this to Owner only it forces a request to the owner when someone wants to share it, it will also not allow them to move it from a public folder.

Using apps script it can be done by this method:
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setShareableByEditors(false);

Comment: Thank you - Based on what you described, could you explain how would you control permissions in a Google App, so if a user clicked on the blue share button, they could not share with anyone else?